# iOS presentViewController freezed when storyboard has a TextView with one word only

Tags: ios, textview

I am having this weird problem in my iOS 9 device, the app just freezed when I try to `presentViewController` to a ViewController designed in storyboard. And the ViewController happens to have a UITextView with single word as the content: `Name`

**How I fixed it:**

After I changed the `Name` to `Name :` (notice the space there), it runs fine now.

This is not really a question, rather than a reminder to those having this weird problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this problem and I removed text from Interface file and put it in programmatically in `viewDidLoad` method.Sometimes space also don't work so better put text programmatically and you can add without space as well.